# How to Pass Dynamic routes in postman collections

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, postman, newman

I have a postman collection which has been integrated with Jenkins with the help of Newman command line options. I am creating routes during deployment, is it possible I can dynamically pass the routes in my postman collection taking it from the Jenkins while the deployment is happening?

Comment: Are you not just talking about using an environment file?

Comment: @danny I don't want to pass the URLs in the environment file. During deployment, we are generating a route and I want to pass that newly generated route.